# Disable activate button when status is approved in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html-table, disabled-control

I am binding the table using ng-repeat in angular js
Here is my table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr. no.</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>PostedOn</th>
      <th>Created By</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Active Blog</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in PostedBlogList | filter:searchText" ng-show="PostedBlogList.length">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td><a ng-href="{{'//'+obj.PageUrl }}">{{obj.Title}}</a></td>
      <td>
        <img style="width:90px" ng-show="obj.Image" src="{{obj.Image}}">
        <img style="width:90px" ng-show="!obj.Image" src="/images/mail.png">
      </td>
      <td>{{obj.CategoryName}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.CreatedDate}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.FirstName}}({{obj.UserType}})</td>
      <td>{{obj.IsActive ? 'Approved ' : 'Pending'}}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)" ng-disabled="" ng-bind="btnactivate" type="submit" value="Activate"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="PostedBlogList.length==0"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am setting the status using `{{obj.IsActive ? 'Approved ' : 'Pending'}}` based on true and false.
on the below `<td>` I have a button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)" ng-disabled="" ng-bind="btnactivate" type="submit" value="Activate"></button>
```

How can I disable the button when my status is approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable button like this `ng-disabled="obj.IsActive"`:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)" ng-disabled="obj.IsActive" ng-bind="btnactivate" type="submit" value="Activate"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir perfect answer